# How do I increase the job chance for a tenant?

Tags: dream-house-days

In Dream House Days, when you view a tenant's details, tap on Trait, then tap on Job, you get a list of all the available jobs you currently know and that tenant's likelihood of getting that job when he or she applies for it. I have seen the percentages for some jobs increase after a while while some jobs stay at a very low chance.

What factors change the job chance of a tenant?

Answer (score 2):

The tenants must have high intellect and fitness for jobs, but some high played jobs also need high hobby and or charisma, so I reccomend getting study sets even if they are adults, books etc from pumpkin products and give them appropriate furniture :) Hope it helped!